# esp8266 Receipt of text via socket from android app

Tags: android, c++

I am attempting to transfer a string from an android app to a esp8266 via a socket.

> ```
> #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
> #include <WebSocketsServer.h>
>
> WebSocketsServer ws = WebSocketsServer(81);  
>
> const char *ssid = "scorer_8";      
> const char *password = "81828384";  
>
>
> /*__________________________________________________________SETUP__________________________________________________________*/
>
> void setup() {
>   Serial.begin(115200);  
>   delay(10);
>
>   startWiFi();  
>
>   startWebSocket();
> }
>
> /*__________________________________________________________LOOP__________________________________________________________*/
>
> void loop() {
>   ws.loop();  // constantly check for websocket events
>
>   Serial.print("S\r\n");
>
>   delay(1000);
> }
>
> /*__________________________________________________________SETUP_FUNCTIONS__________________________________________________________*/
>
> void startWiFi() {  
>   IPAddress local_IP(1, 2, 3, 4);
>   IPAddress gateway(1, 2, 3, 1);
>   IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);
>   Serial.print("Setting soft-AP configuration ... ");
>   WiFi.softAPConfig(local_IP, gateway, subnet);
>
>   WiFi.softAP(ssid, password, 11);  // Start the access point
>
>   Serial.print("Access Point \"");
>   Serial.print(ssid);
>   Serial.println("\" started\r\n");
> }
> /*____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________*/
>
> void startWebSocket() {        
>   ws.begin();                  
>   Serial.println("*********webSocket.onEvent(webSocketEvent);\r\n");
>   ws.onEvent(webSocketEvent);  
>  }
>
> /*____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________*/
>
> void webSocketEvent(byte num, WStype_t type, uint8_t *payload, size_t length) {
>
>   Serial.println("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^");
>
>
>   if (type == WStype_TEXT) {
>     if (payload[0] == '0') {
>
>       Serial.println("LED=off");
>     } else if (payload[0] == '1') {
>
>       Serial.println("LED=on");
>     }
>   }
>
>   else  // event is not TEXT. Display the details in the serial monitor
>   {
>     Serial.print("WStype = ");
>     Serial.println(type);
>     Serial.print("WS payload = ");
>     // since payload is a pointer we need to type cast to char
>     for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) { Serial.print((char)payload[i]); }
>     Serial.println();
>   }
> }
> ```

The android app connects to the esp and begins transmitting the string GJCXXXV1000000015 at one second intervals.

The esp apparently receives the string but does not trigger the webSocketEvent due, I suspect because it still thinks it is receiving the string. Is it because I have to terminate the string at the app end with something.

With Teraterm attached to the esp i get the following:

```
> Setting soft-AP configuration ... fpm close 3 mode :
> softAP(42:f5:20:3d:36:76) 
> add if1 
> dhcp server
> start:(ip:192.168.4.1,mask:255.255.255.0,gw:192.168.4.1) 
> bcn 100 
> bcn 0
> del if1 
> usl 
> add if1 
> dhcp server
> start:(ip:1.2.3.4,mask:255.255.255.0,gw:1.2.3.1) 
> bcn 100 Access Point "scorer_8" started
> 
> [WS-Server] Websocket Version: 2.3.7 
> [WS-Server] Server Started. 
> S 
> S 
> S
> add 1 
> aid 1 
> station: d0:b1:28:e5:fa:a9 join, AID = 1 
> S 
> S
> [WS-Server][0] new client from 1.2.3.103 S 
> [String] ' ... ': Reallocating large String(143 -> 144 bytes) 
> [String] ' ... 015': Reallocating large String(159 -> 160 bytes) 
> [String] ' ... 000015': Reallocating large String(175 -> 176 bytes) 
> [String] ' ... 000000015': Reallocating large String(191 -> 192 bytes) 
> [String] ' ... XV10000000': Reallocating large String(207 -> 208 bytes) 
> [String] ' ... CXXXV10000': Reallocating large String(223 -> 224 bytes) 
> [String] ' ... GJCXXXV10': Reallocating large String(239 -> 240 bytes) 
> [String] ' ... 15': Reallocating large String(255 -> 256 bytes) 
> [String] ' ... 00015': Reallocating large String(271 -> 272 bytes)
```

Any help would be appreciated.